# How to change default directory in Bash for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, bash

How can I change the default directory of windows bash to a folder of my choosing?

EDIT: I guess I should have been more clear. When I startup Bash I want it the directory to be in a location of my choosing like Desktop or something. How do I go about setting a default directory?

Answer (score 46):

If you want change the directory your bash prompt is starting in, you can edit your `.bashrc` file. At the bottom, add:

```
cd ~
```

This will go into your home directory. (you can actually do just `cd`, but I it's clearer to add the `~` IMO)

---

To edit, you can use `vim`. If you don't know how to use it, you can always use `nano` for the time being, but you really should have a look at it, it's really powerful.

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

This will open nano in "full console". At the bottom, you have the few commands you can use (`^` means `control`) Do your changes, hit `ctrl+o` to save the file (write the file). It'll ask you where to write, by default, it's the right location, just hit `enter` and the `.bashrc` file will be saved. Then, you can press `ctrl+x` to exit.

Comment: Where can I find this file? Where is it generally found?

Comment: at `~`. Do you know how to use `vim`? if not, you can use nano: `nano ~/.bashrc` (to exit, press `ctrl+o`, `enter` and `ctrl+x` to save) (`^` means `control`)

Comment: It is wrong solution, every time when you will need to reload .bashrc you will go to that directory.

Answer (score 28):

Steps to set default directory for **Bash on Ubuntu on Windows** to a folder -

1. Open Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.
2. `cd ~` to go to home directory of Ubuntu
3. Type `edit .bashrc` and enter at the Bash. This will open the file in vim.
4. Use `Down Arrow` or `Page Down` key on keyboard to go to the end of the file (there's a helpful *progress bar* at the bottom right corner of the Bash). At the end of this file, you will find `cd ~`, replace `cd ~` with your desired location.
5. Save the .bashrc file. To save the file, click `esc` and then type `:wq` and click enter.

Note:

- To access your hard disk location make sure you include the mount directory first.
- So if want your Bash to open at `C:\dev` whenever you open the Bash. You need to replace the `cd ~` with `cd /mnt/c/dev` at .bashrc file at Ubuntu home directory.

Comment: This works fine. However, Step 4 had me believing that there would be the text, 'cd ~' at the end of the file. If its not... just add `cd /my/new/path`

Answer (score 16):

Just enter `echo "cd ~" >> ~/.bashrc`. This will append "cd ~" to your .bashrc.

.bashrc is executed everytime you start a(n interactive) bash instance.